# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused when deploy on GCP

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

For my deployment I encountered this error SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `insurances`
order by `created_at` desc).
I tried the suggestions in this tutorial
https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/3EYhmYBbsjg by giving the roles to the services. I gave to the service CLOUD SQL ADMIN and EDITOR roles . But still the same problem.
I have this error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused(SQL: select * from `insurances` order by `created_at` desc)
```

Here
the configuration of app.yaml

```
runtime: php72
# env: flex
# runtime_config:
#   document_root: public
runtime_config:
  document_root: public
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: CONNECTION_NAME
env_variables:
  APP_KEY: secret
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  SESSION_DRIVER: database
  APP_NAME: Tripguard Insurance
  DB_CONNECTION: mysql
  DB_DATABASE: database
  DB_USERNAME: root
  DB_PASSWORD: password
  DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME"
```

I have used these credentials with the cloud shell and my queries are returning results.

Comment: Edit your question with the following 1) Include the code that is calling Cloud SQL 2) Include the roles assigned to the service account (`YOUR_PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`). 3) Include the exact error message. Read this link to help create questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I would recommend you to create an Cloud SQL Public Issue under the “Storage and Databases” section from here [1]. Please select the private component as probably you will have to share project specific information, so that it is not visible to the public. One of the Google Cloud Platform Support Agents will assist you to resolve your issue.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list

Answer (score 0):

I solve my challenge by following these suggestions:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run.